# undefined local variable or method `user' for #<Class:0x00000007dc99c8> (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm writing a test to check if the login creates a remember_digest for the user.
This is the schema for the database:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20141015163624) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "remember_digest"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree

end
```

And this is the test file:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "UserPages", :type => :request do  

  describe "signup" do

    before { visit signup_path }

    describe "with valid information" do
      before do
        fill_in "name",         with: "Example User"
        fill_in "email",        with: "user@example.com"
        fill_in "password",     with: "foobar"
        fill_in "password confirmation", with: "foobar"
      end

      describe "after saving the user" do
        before { click_button submit }
        let(:user) { User.find_by(email: 'user@example.com') }

        describe "remember digest" do
          expect(user.remember_digest).not_to be_blank
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But I'm getting this error upon running rspec :

```
`block (5 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `user' for #<Class:0x00000007dc99c8> (NameError)
```

Comment: did you ever get this fixed up?

Comment: @Joe Essey Unfortunately not. I simply removed that test. It seems that login isn't creating a remember_digest in the test environment. But It works correctly when running it in the development environment. I think it has something to do with cookies.

Answer (score 0):

User `before(:each)` or `before(:all)`.  It also appears the object being created is out of scope of the form submission.

Try:

```
describe "signup" do

  before(:each) { visit signup_path }

  describe "with valid information" do

    before(:all) do
      fill_in "name",         with: "Example User"
      fill_in "email",        with: "user@example.com"
      fill_in "password",     with: "foobar"
      fill_in "password confirmation", with: "foobar"
      click_button submit 
    end

    it "has remember digest value" do
      expect(User.find_by_email('user@example.com')).not_to be_blank
    end
  end
end
```

If that doesn't work, it's probably because you don't have access to the User class within your Rspec file.